# Use Cygwin or VM with UNIX for library that requires UNIX?

Tags: windows, unix, cygwin, liblinear

Forgive my ignorance: I need to use a library that requires a UNIX system ([`LIBSHORTTEXT`](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libshorttext/)). Do I need to install a virtual machine with Unix or is Cygwin enough? (I've read quite a few articles about the difference between them but I don't really understand the practical difference for this specific use). Thanks!

**Edit**: The documentation that said that the library needs UNIX is [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libshorttext/doc/libshorttext.html)

Comment: From the docs it appears that this is a python library which only needs "Unix" for make. So Cygwin (or MSYS) should work fine if you have Python for Windows installed (less overhead than running a VM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends on what makes the library "require UNIX".  Looking at it briefly, it appears to be ANSI C and Python, both of which should either compile or be fairly easy to port on a Windows development system. In your case I'd go with Cygwin if you don't already have a development suite running, as it is likely to allow you to just get things running.

A Virtual Machine is a bit more compartmentalized, so much less connection between Windows and the running software. Unless you are planning to use the operating system in the Virtual Machine as a target for your program, it is a bit of overkill in this case, IMHO.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey @Alderin, thanks. I edited the question to show where I saw that the library needs UNIX, if it helps. So you're saying the Cygwin should be fine? I wasn't sure I could actually install something on a shell...

Comment: The cygwin installation includes a bash shell and mock unix environment that allows for unix/linux shell applications to run like they are supposed to. I've had cygwin+python on a Windows system, with no python in Windows, so your setup should work.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would say Cygwin will do, but it depens on how you use the library. And when you say that the library requires a UNIX system what do you mean?  Are you building a python or c++ program?

The main difference between working in cygwin and a VM is that cygwin is still working in a windows environment with windows directories and hardware drivers, whereas a VM have all this emulated as if it actually was a UNIX machine.

Comment: Hey @jimmy, thanks for your reply. I added an edit to the question to show where I saw that the library requires Unix, if that helps... And I'm writing in Python, does it matter?